# Comunity user Case Read/Edit by accounts - parent account(Portal) Contacts

Tags: sharing, customer-portal, partner-portal, role-hierarchy, manual-sharing

I have an account, and its contacts(Community Users) have a parent account(Partner Account), and its Contacts(Partner User).

I want when a Community User creates a case it should be Read/Edit by its parent account Contacts (The Partner Users).

How would I go about setting up permmisions and sharing for this.

I found I can create a trigger on case create to find all ts parent account users from the parent account role assigned to al partner users, then do manual sharing with the case and hose users.

I'm not sure yet what issues that might create but either way I prefer not using apex, I would like to use standard customization.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Which community and partner licence types are you using - customer community or customer community plus?

Comment: Im not sure yet, And when you say "customer community" does that mean useres that use the logins, vs plus that have unlimited logins for those useres? Is that the only difference between them? Eitherway I'm not sure right now.

Comment: Look on the Setup>Administration>Company Profile>Company Information page - there it will list User Licences with the types available to you in Salesforce.

Comment: Ok, putting the license details aside, any chance I can get some help with my original question?

Comment: The licence details matter as it affects how sharing of objects work - it is quite different between Customer Community and Customer Community Plus licences.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what kind of differences there are, can you please explain or provide a link so I can read up about it and then respond appropriately.

Comment: Ok, couple of links https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000204570&language=en_US http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146502/community-sharing-sets-and-sharing-records-high-volume/146505#146505